# History and autocomplete bug in R console

Tags: r

I installed R using apt-get so I got 3.0 version. When I updated from source code to 3.3.1 the console broke down. When I press arrow-up to see previous command I get instead the symbol of arrow-up: **^[[A** 
And when I start to enter some function name and press TAB I actually get the **TAB** character instead of autocomplete. How could I fix the R console and what have I done wrong?

[image]

Here is my compile options:

```
./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no --enable-memory-profiling \
--enable-R-shlib --with-blas --with-lapack --enable-R-profiling \
--with-jpeglib --with-tcltk --with-cairo
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score -1):

When I wrote a question I saw an answer: **--with-readline=no** must be removed from ./configure